# How do you send KML to Google-Earth running locally?

Tags: java, kml, google-earth

(Background: I understand what is KML. I am able to manually create my own KML (using like a text editor for example) or edit a KML example for my own purposes. I found a library to generate KML for me called JAK. So I know how to create the KML object's that I need.

I searched online and I can't seem to find anything about how you can push your KML object onto Google-Earth while it is running locally. Most of the info online is talking about google earth running in a browser.)

---

I have a java app that generates a KML object every x seconds. I need to push each of these the KML objects onto Google-Earth as the KML objects are generated. **Using Java how do I push KML objects onto Google-Earth running locally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a KML with a NetworkLink to your file, and have that NetworkLink refresh every X seconds.  This will allow for auto-refresh in GE.

Then, just have your process generate new KML at the appropriate place on a regular schedule.

Comment: So I would create a KML and manually load that KML in google earth. Then somehow the KML that is loaded will tell google earth to refresh every x seconds? (meanwhile i will be updating the KML that is pointed to by the network link)

Comment: I see there is some info about "network links" located at: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#network_links --> the python example code at the URL seems similar to what you are saying. everytime the google earth updates the network link... will google earth delete the old placemarker and paint a new placemarker? or will it keep the old placemarker and paint a new placemarker?

Comment: The webpage says "Each time the Network Link is refreshed"... does that mean that google earth will NOT auto-refresh every x seconds? (I definitely need google earth to auto-refresh)

Comment: You set the refreshMode and refreshInterval.  See http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#link for more info. If you set the mode to onInterval, it will refresh every x seconds as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the KML object as a temporary KML file first, then launch Google Earth with the KML file as a parameter:-

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "C:/Program Files/Google/Google Earth/googleearth.exe",
        "C:/myfiles/Test.kml"
});
```

I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: that'll let me push one kml to google earth at the open of google earth. i need to push many kmls to google earth after the start.

Comment: @limc Can i know how to run the same from website,i want to open kml when in google earth ,user clicks on link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342733/open-file-link-with-application-on-user-click

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Chris Stayte's code at https://github.com/ChrisStayte/ArcMap_To_Google_Earth

He does what JonnyO suggests but in C# and in the context of synchronizing with ArcMap