# Open file link with application on user click

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth

In my website i have a link to [kml](https://developers.google.com/kml/) file .

When a user clicks on this link ,I want to open this kml file with google earth application.

In android we can do it by using intent and providing content type.

How to do the same is desktop ? [NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494268/open-google-earth-and-load-specific-kml-file-when-user-clicks-link-on-web-page) **But it will not solve the problem.**

**Is there way to ask for user consent if yes open using script?
Can i run any client side script to do this.**

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate of the question you've liked to?

Comment: @amotzg I want to know is there a way to get user consent like then open application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [answer you have linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7521899/1016142):

You generally can't run arbitrary program on the client machine from a web page. With or without consent. You can only do this by installing a browser plug-in after the user consent or otherwise asking the user for actions.
Allowing this will be a security hazard.

You can  use standard web page actions. But then the result can depend on client side user configuration.

It is also mention in the linked answer that you can use the web base Google Earth. And of course you can use some simple client side script to ask confirmation for that if you still like to.